# Transactions not getting recorded

Tags: corda

When i run the flow i do get a done message but when i query the vault I dont see any transactions there. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. The same code was working last week properly.
I am trying to send " Hello" to another node. similar to YO cordaAPP

Here is my flow class

```
package java_bootcamp;

import co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Suspendable;
import net.corda.core.flows.*;
import net.corda.core.identity.Party;
import net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction;
import net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder;
import net.corda.core.utilities.ProgressTracker;

/* Our flow, automating the process of updating the ledger.
 * See src/main/java/examples/IAmAFlowPair.java for an example. */
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
public class TokenIssueFlow extends FlowLogic<SignedTransaction> {
    private final ProgressTracker progressTracker = new ProgressTracker();
    private final Party receiver;
    private final String text;

    public TokenIssueFlow(Party receiver, String text) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public ProgressTracker getProgressTracker() {
        return progressTracker;
    }

    @Suspendable
    @Override
    public SignedTransaction call() throws FlowException {
        // We choose our transaction's notary (the notary prevents double-spends).
        Party notary = getServiceHub().getNetworkMapCache().getNotaryIdentities().get(0);
        // We get a reference to our own identity.
        Party issuer = getOurIdentity();

        /* ============================================================================
         *         TODO 1 - Create our TokenState to represent on-ledger tokens!
         * ===========================================================================*/
        // We create our new TokenState.
        TokenState tokenState = new TokenState(issuer,receiver,text);

        /* ============================================================================
         *      TODO 3 - Build our token issuance transaction to update the ledger!
         * ===========================================================================*/
        // We build our transaction.
        TransactionBuilder transactionBuilder = new TransactionBuilder(notary);
        transactionBuilder.addCommand(new TokenContract.Issue(),issuer.getOwningKey());
        transactionBuilder.addOutputState(tokenState,TokenContract.ID);

        /* ============================================================================
         *          TODO 2 - Write our TokenContract to control token issuance!
         * ===========================================================================*/
        // We check our transaction is valid based on its contracts.
        transactionBuilder.verify(getServiceHub());

        // We sign the transaction with our private key, making it immutable.
        SignedTransaction signedTransaction = getServiceHub().signInitialTransaction(transactionBuilder);

        // We get the transaction notarised and recorded automatically by the platform.
        return subFlow(new FinalityFlow(signedTransaction));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your definition of `TokenState`?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies to everyone. I was not paying attention.
While running the vaultQuery I was specifying the FLOW class instead to STATE class.

Previously
run vaultQuery contractStateType: com.template.HelloFlow:

Correct Way:
run vaultQuery contractStateType: java_bootcamp.TokenState